# Equation to find the degrees of rotation of a once horizontal line

Tags: c++, math, rotation

hey so I have a center of an object and i'm making a line with this center as the start of it, and the mouse position the end of it.

How do I find how rotated the second point (?,?) is around the stationary first point (0,0) ?
**Note:** if the second point were (1, 0) it would be roated 0 degrees.

Comment: [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember SOHCAHTOA? ;) You can use the arctangent (via the standard `atan2()` function) to determine the angle of the line between the origin and an arbitrary point:

```
#include <cmath>

double mouseX = ...;
double mouseY = ...;
double angleInRadians = std::atan2(mouseY, mouseX);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the angle of rotation is `a`, and the second point is `(x,y)` then:

```
a = arctan(y/x)
```

Comment: Not *quite*, because if `x` and `y` are both negative, the signs cancel and you back to quadrant one.

Comment: And this is exactly the reason why most languages have provided an atan2 function.